# Can't save data from Html Asp.net Core to Mysql Using

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-core

I am learning frontend and I face this problem to save data from Html to Mysql in Asp.Net Core:
I have Order Model
OrderDetails Model
and I made ViewModel
Html table coded to add Rows dinamicly
And i get project , supplier and Item by viewdata as select items

All above it was done But can not save the record!!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">

  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container" >
 <div style="align-items:self-end">
  <input type="button" onclick="enabled()" value=" New Purchace Order" style="margin:10px 10px;" id="newOrder" class="btn  btn-info" />

                </div>
      @*      <div class="row bg-info m-1 block">
                <div class="text-center col-md-8">
                    <h1> Purchace Order <span id="countpro"></span></h1>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>*@


      <!-- Order Section -->   
            @*<form asp-action="Create">*@
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="row bg-secondary m-1 block">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="OrderNO" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="OrderNO" id="poNO" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderNO" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div></div>

               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="OrderDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="OrderDate" id="poDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div></div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Status" id="status" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div></div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ProjectId" id="project"  class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProjectId"></select>
                </div></div>
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="SupplierId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="SupplierId" id="supplier"  class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SupplierId"></select>
                </div></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Subject" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Subject" id="subject"  placeholder="Enter Order Description ...." class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
         
     </div> 

      <!-- End Order Section -->

  
        <!-- Item Section -->
            <div class="row bg-primary m-1 block">
                 <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ItemId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ItemId" id="item" asp-placeholder="Select Item ...." class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ItemId"></select>
                </div></div>
                 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UnitId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="UnitId" id="unit" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UnitId"></select>
                </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Qty" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Qty" id="qty"  class="form-control" onkeyup="getTotal()" onchange="getTotal()"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Price"  class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Price" id="price" class="form-control" onkeyup="getTotal()" onchange="getTotal()" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div> </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Total" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Total" id="total" class="form-control bg-danger text-center" disabled value="0" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Total" class="text-danger"></span>

                </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label class="control-label">Add</label>
                    <button class="btn btn-success " onclick=" addRow();"  id="addButton">
                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                    

                </div>

            </div>
     <!-- End Item Section -->
  
         <!-- Table -->
       
                <table class="table " style="width:100%;" id="tablPro">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                             <th>#</th>
                                <th style="width:30%;">Product/Service</th>
                                <th style="width:10%;">Unit</th>
                                <th style="width:10%;">Qty</th>
                                <th style="width:10%;">Price</th>
                                <th style="width:15%;">Total</th>
                              <th style="width:5%;"></th>
                            <th style="width:5%;"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tablePro">
                  <tr>
                     
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                      <td></td>  
                       </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    

            <!-- End Table -->
                  <!--  Total Section  -->

            @* <div class="row bg-teal m-1 block" id="divPrint">*@
                <div class="totalcontainer">
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                      <label asp-for="SubTotal" style="color:Black;"   class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="SubTotal"  id="subTotal"  class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="SubTotal" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <label asp-for="Vat" style="color:Black;"  class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Vat" id="vat" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Vat" class="text-danger"></span>
                       </div>
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                     <label asp-for="GrandTotal" style="color:Black;"   class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="GrandTotal" id="grandTotal" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="GrandTotal" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                   <div class="text-center">
                   <input type="submit" value=" + Save Purchace Order" id="saveBtn" style="margin:10px 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>                  

              
                </div>
    
                  <!-- End Total Section  -->
                  <hr />
                  <!-- End Createor Section  -->
               <div class="row block">
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CreatedBy" style="color:Black;" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CreatedBy" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CreatedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>  </div> 
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="TimeStamp" style="color:Black;"  class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="TimeStamp" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="TimeStamp" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>  </div> 
    </div>
                  <!-- End Createor Section -->



     
           @* </form>*@
</div>



      


@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script src="~/js/addRow.js"></script>


 <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="~/adminlte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
           // $('#saveBtn').click(function() {
    //    var data = $('input').serialize();

    //    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
    //       console.log(data);
    //    }); 
    //});
     $(function () {
            $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CreatePos/Create",
                    data: "{'poNo':'" + $("#poNO").val() +
                    "', 'poDate':'" + $("#poDate").val() +
                    "', 'status':'" + $("#status").val() +
                    "', 'project':'" + $("#project").val() +
                    "', 'supplier':'" + $("#supplier").val() +
                    "', 'Subject':'" + $("#Subject").val() +
                    "', 'item':'" + $("#item").val() +
                    "', 'unit':'" + $("#unit").val() +
                    "', 'qty':'" + $("#qty").val() +
                     "', 'total':'" + $("#total").val() +
                    "', 'subTotal':'" + $("#subTotal").val() +
                    "', 'vat':'" + $("#vat").val() +
                     "', 'grandTotal':'" + $("#grandTotal").val() +  "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                
                         $("#poNO").val("");
                     $("#poDate").val("");
                   $("#status").val("");
                   $("#project").val("");
                  $("#supplier").val("");
                 $("#Subject").val("");
                   $("#item").val("");
                   $("#unit").val("");
                    $("#qty").val("");
                     $("#total").val("");
                    $("#subTotal").val("");
                     $("#vat").val("");
                      $("#grandTotal").val()

                        alert("record has been saved in database");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("there is some error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

And her is the Script File

```
    var value = document.getElementById('item');
    var getItem = value.options[value.selectedIndex].text;
    var unitValue = document.getElementById('unit');
    var getUnit = unitValue.options[unitValue.selectedIndex].text;
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var x = newRow.rowIndex - 1;
       var editBtn =`<button class="btn btn-info" id="editRow">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </button>` ;
    var deleteBtn =`<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow(this)">
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </button>` ;
    //defination of row cells
    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = newRow.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = newRow.insertCell(7);
    // Push row Values into tabel Body
      cell1.innerHTML = x++;
    cell2.innerHTML = getItem;
    cell3.innerHTML = getUnit;
    cell4.innerHTML = qty;
    cell5.innerHTML = price;
    cell6.innerHTML = total;
    cell7.innerHTML = editBtn;
    cell8.innerHTML = deleteBtn;
}
function getTotal() {
    if (price.value != '') {
        let result = price.value * qty.value;
        total.value = result;
        total.style.background = '#040';
        let vatPercentage = 0.15;
        let subtotal = document.getElementById('subTotal');
        let vat = document.getElementById('vat');
        let grandTotal = document.getElementById('grandTotal');     
        subtotal.value = total.value;
        vat.value = subtotal.value * vatPercentage;
        grandTotal.value = +vat.value + +subtotal.value;
    }
    else {
        total.value = '';
        total.style.background = '#a00d02';
    }
}
```

Finally This is the controller

```
     POST: CreatePos/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("OrderId,OrderNO,OrderDate,Subject,Status,CreatedBy,TimeStamp,ProjectId,SupplierId,ItemId,UnitId,Qty,Price,Total,SubTotal,Vat,GrandTotal")] CreatePoModel createPoModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(createPoModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", createPoModel.ProjectId);
        ViewData["SupplierId"] = new SelectList(_context.Suppliers, "SupplierId", "SupplierName", createPoModel.SupplierId);
        ViewData["ItemId"] = new SelectList(_context.PoItems, "ItemId", "ItemName", createPoModel.ItemId);
        ViewData["UnitId"] = new SelectList(_context.Units, "UnitId", "UnitCode", createPoModel.UnitId);
        return View(createPoModel);
    }
```

Please Consider that I am beginner still learning: (

Comment: you can't add createPoModel to context. I will asume that is a model from any kind of Entity Framework Object (Table) then you use _context.Table.Add(Model)

Comment: Thank you so much for opening my mind to this, Could you guide me how to save it, or if you have an clear link to explain this , thankful for you.

Comment: I think that is too much for a comment here and there is a lot of information about this on google that is better than my possible explanation. Also is outside of S.O. guidelines.

Comment: Thank you, and what I want to say is Google always the first destination for us, then if we face difficult in applying what we read then we seek help. Thanks again

Comment: sure, I think the same, but S.O. has several guides for questions that are too broad

Comment: Hi @Majid, "But can not save the record!" Is there any error? Try to set a break point in the Create (HttpPost) method and debug the application, whether this method is executed or not when click the Save button? Whether the data is transferred success or not?

Comment: Besides, check the Ajax data property and the Create method parameters(model binding), they are not matched.